# Optimizar django eliminando querys duplicadas

Tags: django

estoy intentando sacar el numero de productos que tiene cada categoría, pero cada categoría es a su vez padre de otras categorías, por lo que quiero saber cuantos hijos tiene esa categoría y sus categorías hijas, he logrado simplificar la query al máximo de la siguiente forma, pero en el debug de django me sigue apareciendo que tengo 66 querys duplicadas.

¿De qué forma puedo eliminar estas duplicidades?

Con la primera linea de views.py, logró sacar de forma idónea el numero de productos de una categoría, pero el problema lo tengo esencialmente al decirle que me devuelva de la categoría y de sus hijas.

models.py

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
   padre = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, 
           related_name='cat_padre')
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', 
                                    auto_now_add=True)
   upd_date = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.nombre + ' ' + self.pais.iso

class Producto(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
   categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
```

views.py

```
cats = Categoria.objects.annotate(num_productos=Count('producto')).filter(pais__iso=pais, padre__isnull=True).order_by('-num_productos')

for c in cats:
     num_p = Producto.objects.filter(categoria__padre=c).count()
     c.num_productos += num_p

 contexto = {
    'categorias_padre': cats,
}

return render(request, 'web/pruebitas/product.html', contexto)
```

Django debug:

[image: Django entradas duplicadas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He obtenido la respuesta en StackOverflow Ingles:

```
cats = Categoria.objects.annotate(
        num_productos=Count('cat_padre__producto', distinct=True) +
                      Count('producto', distinct=True)).filter(
        pais__iso=pais, padre__isnull=True).order_by('-num_productos')
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981448/optimization-of-querys-in-django-eliminating-querys-duplicates/47983137

Answer (score 0):

Deberias hacer un poco de optimización de consultas en este caso, si ya sabes de antemano q vas a consultar los productos de cada una de las categorías, pudieras hacer *select_related()* ya que tienes una relación de uno a muchos de los productos a las categorías, de esta forma vas a poder usar los productos relacionados sin ejecutar mas consultas a la base de datos,  o sea pudieras hacer:

```
cats = Categoria.objects.select_related('producto').annotate(num_productos=Count('producto')).filter(pais__iso=pais, padre__isnull=True).order_by('-num_productos')
```

en caso de tener relaciones de muchos a uno o de muchos a muchos en otros modelos pudieras usar *prefetch_related()*.

Para mas informacion puedes leer en la documentacion oficial 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Saludos, espero q te resuelva.

Comment: No funciona Yoel, me dice:

FieldError at /
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'producto'. Choices are: padre, abuelo, pais